# How to populate login textbox UserName (not present in designer file) from a session variable?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

A question from a beginner without English as mother language.

I have a Login.aspx file, populated with one `asp:HyperLink` and one `asp:Login`. Inside the login control there are labels, textboxes, and validation procedures inside a layout template.

Inside the designer file, however, there are only hyperlink and login controls. The textbox `UserName` is absent as all other controls inside the Login control.

I want to populate UserName with a session variable at page load, i.e. `UserName.text=Session("Fng").ToString` but got error

> 'UserName' is not declared.

How to work around?

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I learned something new and it works OK. Hopefully this is the right way to appreciate he answer given, otherwise please guide me.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If so , you can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use Login.UserName property to access the textbox UserName.

I designed the following html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
             <asp:Login runat="server" ID="log">
       
        </asp:Login>
        <asp:button id="btnshowusername" Text="showusername" runat="server" OnClick="btnshowusername_Click"></asp:button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

VB.NET code:

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Session("UserName") = "user1"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnshowusername_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        log.UserName = Session("UserName")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Tested result: When you click the button, the Session value is assigned to the textbox `UserName`.

[image]